# Backup websites with database in ubuntu server

Tags: database, ubuntu, backup

I am having one ubuntu local server in which we used to have all our development websites. They all are php based sites. I would like to know whether we can have script or something to cron backup the files and database daily to external harddisc ?

Please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site is for programming-related questions. You should try your question over at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: Also, you may want to have your question cover a specific problem you're having with backups. Yes, you could have a script regularly back up your files. What specifically are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of services, which should help you

- http://jarvys.io - command line tool/service, that provides server backup to the cloud, simple restore process.
- https://bitcalm.com - SaaS for the Linux server files and DBs backups. It has web ui to configure and manage the backups for all you servers. It backs up your data to Amazon S3 (you can use your own storage), recovery is really simple.

I don't have enough reputation to post more links. But you can google services like gobitcan, backuprun, tarsnap - all these are the services that can solve your problem too.